# How to sove 'Error ListView Adapter is hardcoded'?

Tags: java, android

I have been using this ListViewAdpter to create song lyrics until now, when i tried to make up the list of song lyrics up to 900, i had an error while compiling with studio. The error states that ListViewAdapter class is hardcoded. This compilation error kept persisting. I checked Google, and one of the search results says i should create SQLiteDatabaseHelper. Please is there any other way i can bypass this and create the songs lyrics? If mot, can you help me with a guide on how to begin with SQlite. Thank you.

Here is the code

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    //Variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Model> modellist;
    ArrayList<Model> arrayList;

    //Constructor
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Model> modellist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.modellist = modellist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(modellist);
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView mTitleTv, mDescTv;
        ImageView mIconTv;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modellist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return modellist.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            //locate the views in row.xml
            holder.mTitleTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainTitle);
            holder.mDescTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainDesc);
            holder.mIconTv = view.findViewById(R.id.mainIcon);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }
        //set the result into textview
        holder.mTitleTv.setText(modellist.get(i).getTitle());
        holder.mDescTv.setText(modellist.get(i).getDesc());
        //Set the result in imagview
        holder.mIconTv.setImageResource(modellist.get(i).getIcon());

        //listview item clicks
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //code later
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 1")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 001");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 2")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 002");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 3")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 003");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 4")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 004");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 5")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 005");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 6")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 006");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 7")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 007");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
//etc... up to 900 lyrics

            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    //filter
    public void filter(String charText){
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        modellist.clear();
        if (charText.length()==0){
            modellist.addAll(arrayList);
        }
        else {
            for (Model model : arrayList){
                if (model.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)){
                    modellist.add(model);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't hardcode any data in your code. in this case you should create a database for it. use the SQLite database using the `room` library, it's easy to use. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

Comment: I think your your problem is not related to Sqlite Database. You are repeating huge number of code that is not necessary. No need to use 900 condition and 900 times code to pass data to  FavouritesContentActivity Activity. See my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `view` `onClick` in your adapter your action is same.

1. You are navigating to `FavouritesContentActivity`
2. passing some data to that `Activity` through `Intent`

You can do this in one code without checking condition!!

Like

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", modellist.get(i).getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("contentTv", modellist.get(i).getDesc());
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
     }
});
```

If you want to use some part of title as `actionBarTitle` you can `substring` the title.

```
intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", title.substring(0, title.indexOf("|")));
```

It will set "actionBarTitle" value like `"Song 001"`

Comment: I'm sorry for the misconception of wonderful example given above by @Md.Enamul initially, I have substring the title to give me the actionBar title as i want.  My only worry right now is how to set the lyrics for the **"contentTv"**?? Since you said i should use  _intent.putExtra("contentTv", modellist.get(i).getDesc());_

Comment: Please sir, how am i going to feed the lyrics value for the modellist.get(i).getDesc());??? Where and how should I code the lyrics as the description? Thanks for your time

Comment: I don't know your what is your Desc look like. I thought your Desc is Lyric description. What you want? Is the "contentTv" value is part of your Desc? Then comment the Description value so that I can suggest you how to cut and use that in "contentTv".

Comment: Yes Sir, The contentTv is the description. For example, **For song1 Tile, this is the code for lyrics description** intent.putExtra("contentTv", "They say oh my god I see the way you shine, Take your hand, my dear, and place them both in mine");     **For song2 Tile, this is the code for lyrics description** intent.putExtra("contentTv", "Dance for me, dance for me, dance for me, oh, oh, oh,  I've never seen anybody do the things you do before");    and so on...

Comment: If i say intent.putExtra("contentTv", modellist.get(i).getDesc());         the getDesc() draws its content from **row** description... The **row** has one image icon, TextView title, and TextView Desc. So, i used these three objects to construct the Model

Comment: this sub-scripting of actionBarTitle gave me error ``` intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", title.substring(0, title.indexOf("|")));```